# What does a 2 dimensional char array initialize it's values to?

Tags: java, eclipse, multidimensional-array, tic-tac-toe

I'm having a little trouble checking to see my Tic-Tac-Toe game is a draw. It would be easiest to just show you.

Here I initialize a 2d array to represent my Tic-Tac-Toe board, I explicitly make each value a space character (' ') but my isDrawn method won't work correctly.

```
private char[][] board = {{' ',' ',' '},{' ',' ',' '},{' ',' ',' '}};
```

and here is my isDrawn method that I can't seem to get to work.

```
public boolean isDrawn ()
    {
        boolean full = true;
        for (int i=0; i<=2; i++)
        {
            for (int ii=0; ii<=2; ii++)
            {
                if (board[i][ii]==' ');
                {
                    full = false;
                }
            }
        }
        if(isWon()==true)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return full;
    }
```

The isWon() method simply returns true if someone has a winning combination or false if neither X's nor O's have won yet. My thinking with the above method is that by making sure none of the squares contain an empty space like they were initialized to (' '), and by making sure that neither X's nor O's have won yet, then it should be a draw right? Yet in another part of my program I implement a counter that counts how many times there have been draws by calling isDrawn and adding one to the counter if it is true, the draws counter always stays at 0.

Comment: and does isWon() return true/increment its counter?

Comment: Remove that semicolon at the end of your `if` condition.